# Web API 2: Updating Navigational Properites (Entities)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am looking for some guidance with Web API functionality that was a breeze in MVC in regards to updating entities that have navigational properties.

In MVC, it was accomplished as:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Update(Page page)
    {
        Guard.IsNotNull(page, "page");

        var pageToUpdate = await this.repository.Query.Include(p => p.Tags).Include(p => p.Name).SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Pk == page.Pk);

        if (pageToUpdate == null)
        {
            return this.RedirectToRoute(H.Constants.Routes.Error.Index, new
                                                                        {
                                                                            view = H.Constants.Views.Error.ViewPages.NotFound
                                                                        });
        }

        if (this.TryUpdateModel(pageToUpdate))
        {
            this.repository.BeginTransaction();

            this.repository.Update(pageToUpdate); // Updates related entities!

            await this.repository.CommitTransactionAsync();

            return this.RedirectToRoute(H.Constants.Routes.Data.Read);
        }

        return this.View(H.Constants.Views.FolderNames.ViewPages.FormatWith(H.Constants.Views.Data.ViewPages.Update), pageToUpdate);
    }
```

All navigational properties would be updated, and life was well.

When attempting this exact thing in Web API, not so much. The related entities are not updated. Example:

```
    [HttpPatch]
    [HttpPut]
    public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Update(int pk, Page page)
    {
        Guard.IsNotNegativeOrZero(pk, "pk");

        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (page.Pk == pk)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.repository.BeginTransaction();

                    this.repository.Update(page); // Doesn't update related entities.

                    await this.repository.CommitTransactionAsync();

                    return this.StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException dbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (this.repository.Query.Any(p => p.Pk == pk))
                    {
                        return this.InternalServerError(dbUpdateConcurrencyException);
                    }

                    return this.NotFound();
                }
            }

            return this.BadRequest();
        }

        return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
    }
```

Is this possible to do today in Web API? Or is Web API currently an incomplete Microsoft product?

Edit: Updated with example and not referencing WCF

Comment: Are you confusing the transport layer (WCF/WebAPI) with the ORM?  I do not understand what `context.Update(entity)` would have to do with WebAPI.

Comment: No, it is Entity Framework behind both WCF and WebAPI with different behaviors each.

Comment: WebApi is pretty ok, you're just using it wrong. WebApi has nothing to do with data and entities it handles web requests. an Api controller should take the input and send it to a Service and the service will do the updating of entities etc.

Comment: @RyanMendoza, what is `context.Update`?  That sounds like the ORM.  If so, that would have absolutely nothing to do with WebAPI.

Comment: Not sure if my question is translating over well. An example is that in MVC has UpdateModel and TryUpdateModel that allows partial model to be received by the method and update only relevant parts of the model. This does not exist in WebAPI, even though it seems to be modeled off of MVC.

Comment: @Ryan, I suggest you post an example of your WCF code and your WebAPI code; it's difficult to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @RyanMendoza, it depends on how you are using EF, please post a sample code showing the problem. It has nothing to do with WebAPI, are you using Breeze on top of webapi?

Comment: I have updated the question to not reference WCF because I realized that's irrelevant. Also added example of what works with MVC, and what doesn't work with Web API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TryUpdateModel doesn't exist in WebAPI.  You may also find you have issues with seralization of entities.  For both those reasons I use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map ViewModels onto EF entities and you can use Mappings in automapper to deal with your navigation properites.

The web API method looks something like this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (someValidationCheckHere)
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        _myService.Update(Mapper.Map<MyViewModel, MyEntity>(model));

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

As others have said the service and ultimately the repository does the update.  In this example I'm ignoring the navigation property using automapper, but you can configure automapper to handle them how you like:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyEntity>()
            .ForMember(x => x.NavigationProperty, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

I set up all my mappings in a static class called on application_start in global.asax.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Could you provide an example of AutoMappers role in the provided example to solve the lack of TryUpdateModel?